# Update excel cell with stock quotes from NSE (National Stock Exchange)

Tags: vba, excel

Question is related to VBA for excel. I am running MS Excel 2011 on a mac.

Using http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NSE:INFY i am able to get the stock price details. This is an old API from google finance still active.

Was looking for some help to update an excel cell with the price which is returned from the dataset of this API.

It returns something like

```
▶ curl http://finance.google.com/finance/info\?client\=ig\&q\=NSE:INFY

// [
{
"id": "675530"
,"t" : "INFY"
,"e" : "NSE"
,"l" : "1,184.10"
,"l_fix" : "1184.10"
,"l_cur" : "Rs.1,184.10"
,"s": "0"
,"ltt":"3:40PM GMT+5:30"
,"lt" : "Apr 11, 3:40PM GMT+5:30"
,"lt_dts" : "2016-04-11T15:40:45Z"
,"c" : "+18.35"
,"c_fix" : "18.35"
,"cp" : "1.57"
,"cp_fix" : "1.57"
,"ccol" : "chg"
,"pcls_fix" : "1165.75"
}
]
```

I can get this extracted using shell script, but i want it in excel

CLI :

```
curl --silent http://finance.google.com/finance/info\?client\=ig\&q\=NSE:INFY\ > /tmp/ChangeIsInevitable && cat /tmp/ChangeIsInevitable | grep l_fix | sed 's/[",]//g' | awk '{print $3}'
1184.10
```

Answer (score 0):

Did not find a straight forward way using VBA for EXCEL MAC.
So wrote a small shell script to get a CSV. Then import it to the excel

I just wanted to get the latest price of few stock prices on demand.
In order to use this you should have a file called "stocklist" at your home ~
with the stocks that you want
Default search is for NSE, you can change the variable value for **index** to **BSE**

```
#!/bin/bash
index=NSE
filename=~/latestPrice.txt

#Cleanup temp files
cp /dev/null $filename

echo "Stock,Price" >> $filename
for i in `cat ~/stocklist`
do
  curl --silent "http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=${index}:${i}" > /tmp/tmpfile
  stockPrice=`cat /tmp/tmpfile | grep l_fix | sed 's/[",]//g' | awk '{print $3}'`
  echo "$i : $stockPrice"
  echo "$i,$stockPrice" >> $filename
done
```

EDIT:

Since i have started working with python, here is a python version which provides a CSV output.

```
import requests
import json


stocks = [
'NSE:AXISBANK',
'NSE:BAJAJ-AUTO'
]

r = requests.get("http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=%s" % (','.join(stocks)))

result = r.content

result = result.replace("// ","")
data = json.loads(result)
for stock in data:
    print "%s,%s" % (stock['t'], stock['pcls_fix'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [VBA-JSON](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) Git library (which you save directly to stand alone module and reference the Microsft Runtime reference), Excel VBA can parse json objects:

```
Dim jsonStr As String, strPath As String, URL As String
Dim p As Object, element As Variant
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim wb As Workbook 
Dim jsondata As New Collection

strPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

' DOWNLOAD JSON 
Dim objhttp As Object

URL = "http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=MSFT"
Set objhttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") 
With objhttp 
   .Open "GET", URL, False 
   .send 
   jsonStr = Replace(.responseText, "/", "")
End With 

Set p = ParseJson(jsonStr)

' OPEN EXTERNAL WORKBOOK
Set wb = Workbooks.Add 
wb.Activate

' ITERATE DATA ROWS
i = 1
For Each element In p
    If i = 1 Then
        ' HEADERS
        j = 1
        For Each k in element.keys
             wb.Sheets(1).Cells(i, j) = k
             j = j + 1
        Next k
    Else
        ' DATA ROWS
        j = 1
        For Each k in element.keys
             wb.Sheets(1).Cells(i, j) = element(k)
             j = j + 1
        Next k
    End if
    i = i + 1
Next element

Set objhttp = Nothing
Set element = Nothing
Set p = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing
```